# Getting Rpush::Daemon::TcpConnectionError when using rpush

Tags: ruby-on-rails, notifications, openssl, rubygems

I'm getting error when pushing notification using **rpush push**,it gives following error:

```
Will retry 1 notifications after 2016-01-28 14:04:34 due to error (Rpush::Daemon::TcpConnectionError, OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError, SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server session ticket A)
[2016-01-28 14:04:24] [ERROR] Rpush::Daemon::TcpConnectionError, OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError, SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server session ticket A
/home/linchpin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/rpush-2.5.0/lib/rpush/daemon/tcp_connection.rb:162:in `rescue in connect_socket'
/home/linchpin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/rpush-2.5.0/lib/rpush/daemon/tcp_connection.rb:134:in `connect_socket'
/home/linchpin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/rpush-2.5.0/lib/rpush/daemon/tcp_connection.rb:40:in `connect'
/home/linchpin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/rpush-2.5.0/lib/rpush/daemon/tcp_connection.rb:69:in `write'
/home/linchpin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/rpush-2.5.0/lib/rpush/daemon/apns/delivery.rb:12:in `perform'
/home/linchpin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/rpush-2.5.0/lib/rpush/daemon/dispatcher/apns_tcp.rb:32:in `block in dispatch'
/home/linchpin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/rpush-2.5.0/lib/rpush/daemon/dispatcher/apns_tcp.rb:31:in `synchronize'
/home/linchpin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/rpush-2.5.0/lib/rpush/daemon/dispatcher/apns_tcp.rb:31:in `dispatch'
/home/linchpin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/rpush-2.5.0/lib/rpush/daemon/dispatcher_loop.rb:66:in `dispatch'
/home/linchpin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/rpush-2.5.0/lib/rpush/daemon/dispatcher_loop.rb:35:in `block (2 levels) in start'
/home/linchpin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/rpush-2.5.0/lib/rpush/daemon/dispatcher_loop.rb:25:in `loop'
/home/linchpin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/rpush-2.5.0/lib/rpush/daemon/dispatcher_loop.rb:25:in `block in start'
```

Comment: This appears to be related to SSLv3 being rejected by Apple. The same problem just materialized today in the houston gem.